# Golang text/tabwriter not working with strings.Builder as an output io.Writer when using '\t'

Tags: go, text, io

## The problem I am trying to solve

I need to display some data to the user in a formatted form (some kind of table in my case). So I am using `text/tabwriter` package as a simple option. I tried to output formatted strings to the `string.Builder` for further conversion to the simple string type. (`os.Stdout` is not an option in my case).

## Difficulties I have encountered

When I am using `strings.Builder` as an `output` (type `io.Writer`) argument in the `tabwriter.NewWriter()` function it does not actually output anything (see code example in section below). This problem does not appear when I am using `os.Stdout` or any kind of file as an output.

## What did I try to do

I have a test structure that represents some data I need to output:

```
type someData struct {
    FieldOne string
    FieldTwo string
}
```

Function that formats this data and returns a string:

```
func formatData(data []someData) string {
    var builder strings.Builder

    writer := tabwriter.NewWriter(&builder, 0, 0, 3, ' ', 0)
    defer writer.Flush()

    for _, d := range data {
        fmt.Fprintln(writer, d.FieldOne+"\t"+d.FieldTwo)
    }
    return builder.String()
}
```

Function call with test data:

```
data := []someData{
    someData{
        FieldOne: "sample",
        FieldTwo: "data",
    },
    someData{
        FieldOne: "something",
        FieldTwo: "here",
    },
}

fmt.Println(formatData(data))
```

This code is available on [The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/e2NAbsxOWej).

But when I am using `os.Stdout` as an output it works fine. Working code is also available on [The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ZICRHH4gCxT).

Also problem does not appear if I am not using `'\t'` in the string for tabwriter.

(This one: `fmt.Fprintln(writer, d.FieldOne+"\t"+d.FieldTwo)`)

Example with `'.'` instead of `'\t'` is also available. [The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/-lCu-vjB1Lo)

---

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You are `Flush`ing the tabwriter _too_ _late_: You must not flush in a defer as this happens _after_ you call builder.String. You have to flush the tabwriter first to force it writing to builder, and only after that you can call String on the builder.

Comment: @Volker Thanks a lot for your help! I `Flush`ed the `tabwriter` before calling `builder.String()` and this actually worked for me. :3